# Auto-answer "really edit the buffer"

Tags: automation

I frequently have `auto-revert-mode` enabled for log files, where the mode hook runs `ansi-color-apply-on-region`.  That deletes ANSI color sequences and adds overlays to produce the desired color.

That actually edits the buffer, so if additional output is written to the file, I frequently get a `test.log changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)` prompt, which I manually need to answer.

My hook will gracefully handle a `n` answer here, but it's annoying and disruptive to have to keep answering the question.  Is there a good way to automatically answer the question?

I feel like something like `(flet y-or-n-p "n")` wrapping my code is what I want, but I'm not sure which function to override, since `r` is not usually an option in `y-or-n-p`.

Comment: If you want to ask this, please ask it as a separate question (post): *"I'm also unclear on the differences between `flet`, `letf` and the `cl-*` versions"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trigger the stacktrace you'll see that the function that checks file modification and then asks you is `userlock--ask-user-about-supersession-threat`. The function is very short, [just 4 lines](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/5a7c46355be1b5a9a8dbfb36ba44969963a3f558/lisp/userlock.el#L152-L155).

So you can either override the function or add an advice. To override just add a `(defun userlock--ask-user-about-supersession-threat (filename))` to your config. Or maybe a more interesting way: add an `:around` advice that avoids calling the original function when the `filename` looks like a log file.

So e.g. since you wanted to answer `n` every time, here's an advice to avoid asking the question when it's a log file that's being edited.

```lisp
(defun dont-prompt-reverting-advice (orig-func filename)
  "Avoid prompting about externally modified log files."
  (unless (string-suffix-p ".log" filename)
    (funcall orig-func filename)))
(advice-add #'ask-user-about-supersession-threat :around #'dont-prompt-reverting-advice)
```